# How can I change angular-route.js from using Ajax to script-tag loading of partials?

Tags: angularjs, security, single-page-application, offline, angular-routing

I am making a mobile, AngularJS, cross-browser, offline spa with angular-route.js using no server at all.  I feel changing browser defaults to allow Ajax loading of local files unacceptable for my situation.  Ideally I would like an external-to-library code work-around that allows loading files via script-tag src attribute manipulation.  But, I am willing to explore modifying or extending an open source library file such as angular-route.js if I knew the best version + file + line to start with.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to use [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache), you can specify the templates directly in your html using a `<script>` tag.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id"path/to/template.html">...</script>
```

Of course you will probably want to have each partial in a separate file, in which case you will have to add a task that will make the partials available to `$templateCache`. There are plugins that will do this for you, take a look at [grunt-ng-template](https://github.com/duckbox/grunt-ng-template).

Comment: Perhaps I am hoping for the impossible, but I would like to lazy load the partial and eliminate it from memory upon view change or on programmer determined event.  The grunt approach seems like a pre-load of all partials at once.  Anyone know a plugin/library that can do what I want?  I will explore $routeStateChange in combination with document.write("<script...") and direct $templateCache handling.  I'm not sure how to nullify memory held by loaded javascript after script tag load.  If anyone has already done this, their sample code would resolve a lot of open questions.

Comment: Could you update your question with an example of what the code would look like? Am not sure I understand what you mean by lazy load the partial using <script> tags and then eliminate from memory?
Tho, I get the impression that you could achieve what you want by manually requesting and remove templates from angular. You can manually request a template using [$templateRequest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateRequest), they will automatically get added to $templateCache

Comment: Does standard routing leverage this same $templateRequest?  Your post is helping me narrow the cause of the basic problem (need to debug into Angular files more).  I cannot use $templateRequest because it relies on Ajax.  It will take weeks to post any code since this is a hobby rather than my job.  My existing code is not post worthy in its current state since it does not yet factor in what I've learned from this thread.  I will post again when possible.  Thanks.

Comment: Faking the $templateCache, similar to the following, has some of what I want.  I will see if I can replace the Ajax call to instead use a dynamic insertion of a script tag into the DOM with the partial/template data in that.

Comment: I think I got it, you can't use ajax request and to optimize the memory usage you don't want to have all the templates loaded. What you could do is generate the templates using a plugin like grun-ng-template, which will create a script file that add a template to $templateCache, but you create one file per template. This way when you add the <script> tag dynamically it will mean that you load the template, to remove it from memory, you would just delete it from the $templateCache

Comment: Your understanding of my goal is correct.  I haven't tried the grunt-ng-template plugin yet.  I almost got it working now, but the appended script load appears to be async even when I specify scrpt.async=false.  And since I am setting the partial text into a global variable from within the javascript file, the result is I get no content on page one, page one content where expecting page two, etc.  I would prefer to avoid jquery.  Is the another way to guarantee waiting for the script to load?  script.async = false;
   document.head.appendChild(script);

Comment: Since I cannot find a reliable synchronous mechanism for loading dynamically added script tags, I will attempt to preload all partials referenced by the current partial, then block all view changes that are not yet loaded by first checking if the corresponding partial is loaded yet.  I will try to post again if successful.

Comment: I have it mostly working.  Option 1 is to have all partials loaded in index.html via static script tags, consequence is high memory use.  Option 2 is to dynamically insert script tags, consequence is no good way to jump into the middle of appiThis is an old source, but still seems relevant and helpful

Comment: How about implementing your own $templateRequest service? That way when you use an angular template (ng-include) internally angular will use the $templateRequest if the template is not in $templateCache, which will be your own implementation that takes care of adding the dynamic <script> tag and putting the content into the $templateCache. That's probably where you can intercept the template request, instead of looking into intercepting the routes.

Comment: Using script tags to load partials does seem to work so long as they are static references loaded from index.html.  Once I move to dynamically inserted script tags they must be async, so even with callback methods I cannot guarantee every predicted user click will be loaded and activated in time.  I think the same limitation would occur with my own $templateRequest.  Perfect solution with memory management is elusive.

Comment: The same happens for $templateRequest, the template load is async, which is why $templateRequest returns a promise. http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html
You can create your own promises using the angular $q service

Comment: I already tried a callback method at the bottom of my dynamically loaded script file, which appeared reliable for my cases.  Unfortunately, the initiator thread ("the father") has already completed ("cooked dinner"), before the spawned thread ("the child checking forecast") completes.  I don't see how the promise would be any different.  Initial page attempts preload of links, but user clicks link faster than preload completes.  I need synchronous.  I think I will give up, use static, and risk out of memory for too many, or too big of a partial list.  Thank you for all the help!  Learned alot.

Comment: FYI: I haven't solved the potential, theoretical memory issues if using tons of partials (though I haven't encountered problems yet).  But, I do have a much more elegant partial loading technique now whereby I solve the offline loading of partials by using a fake server with sinon-server-1.12.1.js.  The fake server still relies on static script tag loading, but now I can code some natural AngularJS and it works offline in several browsers (both Windows and Android) without a web server and without security changes.